# How to disable Qt dialog default button changing with tab navigation

Tags: qt, navigation, tabs, defaultbutton

In Qt 4, by default, tabbing through a dialog changes the default button to be the button tabbed to.  This makes tabbing look a bit ugly and distracting as extra redraws take place during tab navigation which distract from point of user focus.

Is there a way to disable this Qt functionality and leave the default button unmodified by tab navigation?

Comment: Does Qt do something non-standard compared to most applications in this regard?

Comment: Correct, the default button normally does not change, one uses the space bar to depress the button with focus, return is reserved for the default button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QPushButton's autoDefault property is responsible for this behavior. By default it's value is true.

Setting it to false for all relevant buttons will prevent them from becoming default when focused.